# Batch Render 300 Objects

Tags: rendering

so let me break down how this is set up. I have 1 camera with all the settings I want. I have 360 objects in my collection all each at 0,0,0. I need to render each of those on their own. Hiding all of them and hitting render, then hitting save as is an insane tedious process. So im looking to automate this, i can't seem to find a plugin or script to do this to save my life, ya'll got anything for me to check out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Head over to the *Scripting* tab and run this little script:

```
import bpy
import os

# hide all meshes from rendering initially
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.type == "MESH":
        obj.hide_render = True

outputdir = "<path/to/your/output directory>"  # replace

# batch render all objects one by one
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.type == "MESH":
        obj.hide_render = False  # only render this mesh
        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = os.path.join(outputdir, obj.name)
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still = True)
        obj.hide_render = True   # hide again after being rendered
```

Comment: So i gave this a go and heres what error its giving me, I have no clue how to properly format code of any sort so im sure i just have something wrong

Comment: Python:   File "E:\2023 ArtWork\HDRInoBackground.blend\Text", line 9
    outputdir = "<E:\2023 ArtWork\Roblox Work\News>"  # replace
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 28-29: malformed \N character escape

Comment: @K9Tvz because your string needs to be a raw string literal. add an `r` before the opening quotation mark to indicate it is a raw string, so the backslash will not escape the next character like `outputdir=r"E:\2023 ArtWork\HDRInoBackground.blend\Text"` or escape the backslash by using the format `E:\\2023 ArtWork\\HDRInoBackground.blend\\Text` or you could even use forward slashes.

Comment: I don't understand any of that BUT i did that and it seemed to of work lol so thank you!

Comment: Does the script above use my current render settings for cycle / camera?

Comment: Also this script is working great but it seems to be rendering black images of old meshes that are no longer in my scene, is there a way to clean up that old data?

Comment: try *File > Cleanup > Everything*